# Real time console output (Live output) while running a UNIX Shell script from Java

Tags: java, shell, unix, ssh, jsch

Requirement is to display the real time streaming of script execution output  to the User on UI.

I have a UNIX Shell script having more than one commands with sleep command in between. I need to read the console output after executing each command from Java.

I am using JSCH (JCraft) to connect to UNIX server and to run the Shell script. I am able to get the console output after executing a complete script. But not able to get after each command execution.

Here is a UNIX Shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash 
echo "Executing touch ChaosMonkey"
sleep 5
echo "Connection and Execution Successfully"
if [ $? = 0 ]
then
  echo "Monkey executed successfully"
else
  echo "Monkey execution returned with error" $?
fi
```

P.S. I cant go with file approach where I can put that o/p into file and read that file through other SSH connection.

Comment: Please post your Java code also.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is a solution for this issue:

Here is a snippet of Java code (JSCH). In the while loop, you will receive real time console output.

```
        channel=session.openChannel("exec");
        ((ChannelExec)channel).setCommand("bash /tmp/temp.sh");
        channel.setInputStream(null);
        channel.setOutputStream(System.out);
        InputStream out = channel.getInputStream();
        channel.connect();          
        StringBuilder outputBuffer = new StringBuilder();
        byte[] tmp = new byte[1024];

        while (true) {
            while (out.available() > 0) {
                int i = out.read(tmp, 0, 1024);
                if (i < 0)
                    break;
                outputBuffer.append(new String(tmp, 0, i));
            }
            if (channel.isEOF()) {
                break;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(" console output::::::::::: "+ outputBuffer.toString());
        System.out.println("Channel exit-status: " + channel.getExitStatus());
        channel.disconnect();
```

Comment: This snippet only prints console output after exiting the while loop. It doesnt do what you wanted on the question.

Comment: To get it display on UI, its more stuff to do that. After getting this real time logs, you can save it into any Collection and hook with Event Emitter which will continuously send this logs to UI application which will be listening to it via web socket. I have implemented end to end thing and project is available on github. Check resiliency-studio-agent folder.  https://github.com/att/Resiliency-Studio